# How can I get this class to run in python?

Tags: python, class, object, show

```
class script(object):

    def __init__(self, time_delay = 1.5):
        self.time_delay = time_delay
        self.lines = []

    def run_script(self):
        for line in self.lines:
            print line
            sleep(self.time_delay)


intro = script(1.5)
intro.lines = ["great", "boy"]
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the `sleep()` function is from the `time` library. Just add

```
from time import *
```

at the beginning of the file. But, since the syntax above will import definitions as if they were declared in your file, you can use:

```
import time

...
time.sleep(self.time_delay)
```

**But** there is also another possibility. That `sleep()` has to be a function declared by you. If this is the case, you have to define it:

```
class script(object):
    # ...

def sleep(delay):
    # implementation
```

**Note:**

- As @icktoofay commented, you are not using the `run_script()` method, so may want to add a call like:

  ```
  intro.run_script()
  ```

Answer (score 0):

There might be confusion on your part about "running" a class, since you don't "run" a class, but you can "run" a method of a class. Perhaps you just mean

```
 intro.run_script()
```